# how to swtich to specific bl_category of N panel?

Tags: python, interface

The command to open the N panel is known to be ：bpy.context.space_data.show_region_ui = True.
But there are many bl_category on N panel，After the command is opened, it need to click on the specific bl_category to jump to，Now is there a code to open the N panel and jump to a specific bl_category in one go?

Comment: No, you can't change tabs via python